# VSCode Debug - Prepend command when launching for django?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've recently started using VSCode to debug with Django and it's worked out pretty well.

I use a system for managing my environment variables however that requires the use of it's keyword first (`keys python manage.py runserver`)

Debugging works fine for firing up a standard Django install - but I can't seem to get the python debugger to run the above statement.

In my `launch.json` I've tried a few configurations like the following:

```
# launch.json
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "keys-run",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver"
        ],
        "django": true
    }
# tasks.json
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "keys-run",
        "command": "keys"
    }
```

I've tried this as well:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "keys",
        "args": [
            "python", "manage.py", "runserver"
        ],
        "django": true
    }
```

The second config give me an error that there is no such file or directory '/home/username/project_directory/keys'

But from the command line (zsh) I can run the command: `keys python manage.py runserver` and it loads my environment variables as it should, then loads up and runs django without issue.

What is the best way to get this into VSCode debugger?

Comment: -How to understand "can't seem to get the python debugger to run the above statement." Have you tried using "python manage.py runserver"?
I execute "python manage.py runserver" in the terminal and it shows that the connection is successful.

Comment: Yes, I can run 'python manage.py runserver' in the terminal without issue. I can also run 'keys python manage.py runserver' in the terminal and it works. I'm trying to use the built-in VS-Code debugger though. It works if I want to run it without keys.... but I need keys to be the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use environment variables instead? Here's an example of how I have a trigger variable (via `"env"`) to turn on/off for Django Debug Toolbar:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "env": {"DJDT": "1"},
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "0:8047",
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

If you can't get that to work, what about `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/keys manage.py"`?

Comment: Hello - thanks for the response! I had no luck either way unfortunately. For some reason it just doesn't care to run 'keys' ahead of 'python manage.py runserver' - perhaps this simply isn't possible and I'm stuck without debugging if I want to use keys.